# When i run ssh in cygwin, nothing happens

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I recently installed ssh in cygwin, but when I tried to run it, absolutely nothing happens. No error, no waiting, it just goes directly to the next line in cygwin. I tried the same exact command on the same network with my friend's version of cygwin and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the actual ssh command? And are you sure the command prompt you got after invoking ssh was from the local machine and not the remote host?

Comment: Yes, I'm invoking ssh from the local machine. The command is standard: ssh username@ipaddress

Comment: I'm just asking if you are 100% sure that you did not actually log in to the remote host. If your login doesn't need a password, all you would see after successful execution is the prompt from the remote machine. Because that's all I can think of, if it failed there should be an error message.

Comment: Also you could try verbose mode with ssh -v

Comment: I'm definitely not accidentally logging in and typing in 'ssh -v' outputs nothing, not even an error message. Might it be a Cygwin problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems others have had this problem, take a look at this thread

https://serverfault.com/questions/26150/ssh-does-nothing-no-matter-what-command-line-it-get-cygwin

It seems the recommended fix is a reinstall.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that! I confirm that reinstalling solved the problem